# How to retrieve a node based on its top-most parent node in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a hierarchy of node relationships like:

Organisation -> Department -> System -> Function -> Port - > Request -> Response -> Parameter

The query -

```
   MATCH q=(p)-[*]->(b:checkoutby) WHERE p.name ="william" RETURN q
```

gives the entire network belonging to the Parent node -> william up-till the last node mentioned -> checkoutby.

[image: hierarchical network]

However, I want only the two related nodes to appear.

I tried the query -

```
  MATCH (n:william) WHERE n is null RETURN n UNION MATCH  n=(p)- 
   [:Parameter]->(b)  WHERE         
    b.name ="checkoutBy"   RETURN n
```

But here the effect of "william" node i.e. the first parent node is nullified and we  get the  output irrespective of the parent node.

For which, I even tried this query -

```
   MATCH (n) WHERE none(node in nodes(n) WHERE node:william) RETURN n 
   UNION MATCH  n=(p)--()-[:Parameter]->(b)  WHERE b.name ="cabinet" 
   RETURN n
```

but I get error -

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type mismatch: expected Path but was Node (line 1, column 36 (offset: 35))
>   "MATCH (n) WHERE none(node in nodes(n) WHERE node: william ) RETURN n UNION MATCH     n=(p)--()-[:Parameter]->(b)  WHERE b.name ="cabinet"   RETURN n"

I even tried the intersection query but to no avail .

```
  MATCH (n1:william), (n2),(q:cabinet)
  WHERE (n1)<-[:Department]-() AND (n2)<-[:Parameter]-(q)
  RETURN count(q), collect(q.name)
```

**Warning Error-**

This query builds a Cartesian product between disconnected patterns.

If a part of a query contains multiple disconnected patterns, this will build a Cartesian product between all those parts. This may produce a large amount of data and slow down query processing. While occasionally intended, it may often be possible to reformulate the query that avoids the use of this cross product, perhaps by adding a relationship between the different parts or by using OPTIONAL MATCH (identifier is: (n2))

```
   EXPLAIN MATCH (n1:william), (n2),(ego:cabinet)
           ^
```

Even this query doesn't work -

```
  MATCH (n:william)  RETURN n UNION MATCH  n=(p)-[:Parameter]->(b)  
  WHERE b.name ="checkoutBy" 
   call apoc.path.expandConfig(n, {labelFilter:'-william'}) yield path
    return path
```

I want to retrieve the checkoutby / cabinet node only if it is from the topmost parent node (william).

Comment: You have a very odd data model here. Please understand that labels are usually meant to be types, and not instances of types, so a :Person node with a `name:'William'` property would make sense, but a :william node doesn't really work. Also your relationship types seem more like what your node labels should be. This is a very confusing data model, and it makes it tough to understand what you're modeling and what data you want back.

Comment: We have made a codethat creates and runs the query in neo4j . So for easy use my label and property name are the same for a particular node for making our code easier to be accessed for further use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputations to comment so asking here:

It's not clear from your question if *William* is a Name property or a Label?

You used it as a *name* in the first query and as a *Label* in all other queries.

I am assuming it is a Label, It looks like it is a label from the screenshot you shared.

If you want to check if the checkoutby/cabinet node is related to William node and return only if it's related you can use the following query:

```
MATCH (w:william)-[*]-(c:checkoutby) return w,c
```

> Please note: These type of queries consumes too much Memory.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your problem the    (b:checkoutby) node does not have any incoming relationships so you could write :

```
MATCH (p)-[*]->(b:checkoutby) WHERE p.name ="william"  AND NOT EXISTS ( (b)-[]->()) RETURN p, b
```